# How to set PATH variable in crontab via whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, whenever, whenever-capistrano

Is it possible to set the PATH or SHELL variable in a crontab via the whenever schedule.rb file?

```
# here I want to set the PATH and SHELL variable somehow

every 3.hours do
  # some cronjob
end
```

I want this output in my crontab after my capistrano deploy:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11
# some cronjobs
```

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems as I found the solution. I found it here: https://gist.github.com/jjb/950975

I will update this answer when I have tested it

I have to put this into my schedule.rb

```
# If your ruby binary isn't in a standard place (for example if it's in /usr/local/bin,
# because you installed it yourself from source, or from a thid-party package like REE),
# this tells whenever (or really, the rails runner) where to find it.
env :PATH, '/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin'
```

Comment: This worked and put the PATH variable in front of my cronjobs.

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing it when running zenity when setting `DISPLAY`, `LANG` etc.

If you want to set the shell, set it in the first line of `/home/username/script/script1.sh` using `#!/bin/bash`.

If you want to set the path, one way to do it is to set it before running the command:

```
5    9-20 * * * PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11 /home/username/script/script1.sh > /dev/null
```

A alternate/better way is to create a simple wrapper script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11

# Absolute path to this script
SCRIPT=`readlink -f $0`
# Absolute directory this script is in
SCRIPTPATH=`dirname $SCRIPT`

#make sure we are in the same directory as the script1.sh - this is useful in case the script assumes it is running from the same directory it's in and makes relative directory/file references
cd $SCRIPTPATH



##run final script, and pass through all parameters that were passed to wrapper script.
/home/username/script/script1.sh "$@"
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear enough. I want to know how to do it with the whenever gem. Or do I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: What do you mean by the whenever gem?

Comment: I mean this gem here: https://github.com/javan/whenever. Super easy to maintain your cronjobs for your rails application. I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: start the whenever gem with this wrapper script. The wrapper script provided allows you to run bash commands (set environment, set path) before running the whenever gem, which you cannot easily do in your cron file.